# pip install flask-mysql-connector

Tags: python, flask, pip

Estoy haciendo un curso de Flask y Al querer instalar el connector de mysql dentro del entorno de (venv) me tira el error de la imagen. y al querer ejecutar el servidor de flask:
so windows 10

> - Serving Flask app 'holamundo.py' (lazy loading)
> - Environment: development
> - Debug mode: on
>   Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
>   Try 'flask run --help' for help.
>
> Error: While importing 'holamundo', an ImportError was raised:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "d:\google
> drive\facu\udemy\python sin
> fronteras\intro-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 256,
> in locate_app
> **import**(module_name)   File "D:\Google Drive\Facu\Udemy\Python sin fronteras\intro-flask\holamundo.py", line 2, in 
> import mysql.connector ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

[image: pip install flask-mysql-connector]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo resolvi ejecutando desde la consola de gitbash y luego de iniciar nuevamente el entorno con ". venv/scripts/activate" me dejo descargar mysql-connector-python sin problema.